# PHP password_hash return value and SQL

Tags: hash, passwords

There are lots of questions about password_hash() function but non answered my question:

I am trying to find information about password_hash function return value. All I see is that it returns the actual hash.

I am planning to save the hash in SQL table.

Can the hash contain quotes? If it can contain quotes, will I have to escape the hash before inserting it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for escaping a BCrypt hash, regarding SQL-injection. A BCrypt hash calculated by password_hash() is base64 encoded, it contains only "harmless" characters of this alphabet...

`./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

...plus the `&` sign to separate the parameters. That said, it is still a good idea to use parametrized queries of course.

Comment: Yes, parametrized queries are the way to go indeed.  Good to know that password_hash() is base64.